# Render pdf with page specific footnotes in ruby

Tags: ruby, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, prawn

I'm looking for a way to render a pdf document with footnotes, where the footnote text appears in the footer of the same page as the footnote reference (as opposed to end of document). This kind of footnotes appears in books, e.g. where translator's comments are. Being able to link the footnote ref with footnote text is optional.

So far I looked at Prawn and PDFKit, but I cannot seem to find a straightforward solution.

This is a sample of what I'm trying to do: [footnote sample](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18515331/footnote.pdf)

And this is what I've come up with using Prawn. Obviously this needs more work to cover corner cases. I'm wondering if it's worth to go further down that route or maybe try something completely different, like latex (haven't used it with ruby).

> ```
> Prawn::Document.generate("foo.pdf",:page_size => 'A4') do
>   #read 150 lorem ipsum records of various length 
>   records = File.read(
>     Rails.root.join("lib/assets/lorem_ipsum_paragraphs.txt")
>   ).split("\n").reject(&:blank?)
>   #assign some random footnotes to the paragraphs
>   footnotes = {
>     1 => '* ' + records[120],
>     2 => '* ' + records[54],
>     11 => '* ' + records[2]
>   }
>   #this array will hold the current footnotes to draw
>   #the assumption being we'll draw them on the current page as soon as we
>   #reach the part of the page where we need to fit those
>   footnotes_to_draw = []
>   #this will hold the amount of space required to draw the footnotes
>   space_needed = 0
>   for i in 0..records.length
>     str = records[i]
>     if footnotes.keys.include? i
>       str += '*'#this one has a footnote attached
>       footnotes_to_draw << footnotes[i]
>       space_needed += (height_of(footnotes[i]) + 15)
>     end
>     text "#{str}"
>     if space_needed > 0
>       #that means we will need to draw a footer on this page
>       space_available = cursor
>       puts "space needed: #{space_needed}, space available: #{space_available}"
>       #check if we can still draw the next record, or now's the time'
>       unless space_available - space_needed > height_of(records[i+1])
>         puts "draw footer now"
>         bounding_box [0,space_needed], :width => bounds.width, :height => space_needed do
>           stroke_horizontal_rule
>           footnotes_to_draw.each do |footnote|
>             pad(10){text footnote}
>           end
>         end
>         #reset current footnotes
>         footnotes_to_draw = []
>         space_needed = 0
>         move_down space_needed
>       end
>     end
>   end
> end
> ```

Comment: Hi Agnessa, welcome to SO. A lot of his computer folks might be skeptical of opening and downloading a wild PDF. You should considering adding more clear example in your question so that people will have an easier time to assist you.

Comment: Hello, thank you, I improved the description.

Comment: I think this problem might be more complicated than you realize Agnessa. There are huge problems with formatting to take into account. What if the foot note is so long it extends to the following page? Should the entire document be re-rendered where the page numbers no longer match from the source? There are a lot more details that need to be considered before a question like this can be answered. Its also typical to post some possible solutions you've attempted yourself.

Comment: Thank you, the problems you are referring to are exactly the reasons why I come to a forum of experts, being ignorant myself, in the hope that someone could point me in the right direction. I added a possible solution of my own, which works for simple cases.

Comment: For the record, I ended up using latex, footnotes work out of the box.